# improve readability by alternating background colors in a list

Tags: javascript, list, react-native, background-color

I am using ListItem from 'react-native-elements' and have a long list of products.

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
      {
        this.state.displayArray.map((item, i) => (
          <ListItem key={i} 
                    bottomDivider
                    style={styles.listWidth} 
                    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('ProductDetails', {productId: 
                    parseInt(item.id)})}>
                <Icon name='shopping-cart' />  
                <ListItem.Title style={styles.listTitle}>{item.name}</ListItem.Title>
                <ListItem.Subtitle style={{ color: '#F78400'}}>{i18n.t("information.cost")}: 
                   {item.cost}</ListItem.Subtitle>                  
                 </ListItem>
                ))
              }
</View>
```

I would like to know if you have an idea to improve readability by alternating the background colors (ex: white, gray, white, gray, white, ....), a bit like that (I'll see for a color more fun maybe :) )

[image: example of result expected]

Comment: in which tag do you want to give background color

Comment: When you map the array, you can use the index to conditionally set a `className` prop or a `style` prop or any other prop used to discriminate whether the element should have a grey background or not. E.g. `<ListItem isGrey={i % 2} ...>...</ListItem>` or `<ListItem className={ (i % 2) ? 'greyBg' : 'redBg' } ...>...</ListItem>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we use simple mod logic, to determine even rows for alternate colors,

An even number % 2,  will always return 0, while an odd % 2 will always return 1 ,using this logic we use i index  such as,
(i % 2 == 0) ? even row : odd row

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
      {
        this.state.displayArray.map((item, i) => (
          <ListItem key={i} 
                    bottomDivider
                    //check mod for even odd rows and assign color
                    style={{backgroundColor: i % 2 === 0 ? '#000' : '#ccc' } 
                    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('ProductDetails', {productId: 
                    parseInt(item.id)})}>
                <Icon name='shopping-cart' />  
                <ListItem.Title style={styles.listTitle}>{item.name}</ListItem.Title>
                <ListItem.Subtitle style={{ color: '#F78400'}}>{i18n.t("information.cost")}: 
                   {item.cost}</ListItem.Subtitle>                  
                 </ListItem>
                ))
              }
</View>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this well documented and very well explained answer. It's very nice to have clear explanations, I'm learning. I did not know this method at all. Thank you very much.
I used containerStyle, style not working. thanks again